# Easiest way of comparing two lists in C# with LINQ and adding missing items to Entity Class

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, compare

I have two lists  in my C# application like following (names):

```
- prepared
- DBList
```

The prepard list of type TransactionDetails contains missing items which I need to add in DBList.

So for example if I have these items in prepared list like following:

```
TransactionID

1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

And my DBList has:

```
TransactionID 
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

I want to compare these two lists, find matching TransactionIDs that are not in DBList and then add them to the DBList. After that I'll clear the prepared list and save changes in DB;

This is what I did so far:

```
var newList = prepared.Intersect(DBList).ToList();
prepared.Clear();
ctx.EbayUserTransactions.AddRange(newList);
ctx.SaveChanges();
```

But the newList list is always empty for some reason.. How can I do this properly?

Edit, the output of DBList items would be:

```
  TransactionID

    1
    2
    3
    4
    5
    6
    7
    8
    9
```

Comment: Have you tried `prepared.Except(DBList).ToList()` ? Does DBList implements IEnumerable<int> ?

Comment: @MatteoMarciano-MSCP Yes but how does the Except method knows which attribute to compare in the two of the lists... The attribute with which I'm comparing them is TransactionID

Comment: Didn't have much clue about the shape of your class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ:

```
DBList.AddRange(prepared.Where((i) => DBList.FindIndex((el) => el.Transaction.ID == i.TransactionID) == -1));
```

Comment: Wow much more simple than I could've imagined. Hold on I'll try this ! :)

Comment: it gives me an exception like this: Unable to create a constant value of type 'DB_Layer.EbayUserTransactions'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context

Comment: it tells me that there is no FindIndex method ?

Comment: @User987, Your lists type are `List<TransactionDetails>`?

Comment: Ah sry the DBList was type of DBSet, I just casted it into the list like: .ToList().FindIndex()

Comment: yes it works like a charm =) .. I love the fact that the solution is a one liner piece of code, just what LINQ offers and does! :D